# DHT22: Library and Data accuracy

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, sensors

I am using DHT22 temperature/humidity sensor and I noticed that there exist so many libraries. I wonder which one is the most accurate?

It is giving me readings that does not seem to be logic. High temperature and very low RH%. Is it because of the library or because I am not connecting 10k or 4.7k resistor?

Thank you so much in advance.

Regards,
Badr Eddine

Comment: Did you try other libraries?

Comment: Did you try connecting the resistor?

Comment: Yes, when I tried other libraries, similar results giving me low humidity level. 
I did not try the resistor. Is it mandatory?

Comment: have the same problem <20% and in real its 68%

Comment: For the DHT units (11 and 22 and AM2302) you want the Adafruit_Sensor and DHT libraries.  Have you tried those?  Plus, it would be very helpful to see your code in a question like this.